# Python script to download video from a forum

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to automate a boring task (ofcourse with your help!). Im a big fan of wrestling, and the episodes of wrestling gets updated each Tuesday & Wednesdays in a website.

I would like to develop a script which downloads the new episode, requirement is just to download the video, i can launch the script manually.

desirulez.cc > Wrestling > Weeklies > WWE raw > here you'll have the latest update row, after you need to navigate to that page to find the download link.

Comment: What have you tried so far? there's probably a module to leverage

Comment: i haven't tried so far, am not an expert with python yet, just started to learn about different libraries, just wanted to explore this side to see if its possible.

Comment: I'd probably drive a headless chrome with selenium to get the download link, then urlfetch it.